# How to make render() in react.js wait for my array to be populated with objects from xml

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

Alright so I've been searching a lot for a answer, and tried everything I came across but nothing seems to do the trick, so now I'm hoping for someone to come to my rescue.

I have a simple function in react, it gets me data from a xml and then populates a state (array) from which I want to present the data in my render(). However, since it gets the data async, the render() seems to fire before the list is populated. I've tried multiple ways to populate the list, setting timeouts, and or loading boxes but my array still seems to come out as undefined, or atleast the objects will.

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance for helpful advice. Also, have in mind, this was not my first approach to populate the array, it's just in the state I left it in for this post.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
//import './Conditions.css';

class GridConditionsXML extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            locationArray: ['Visby', 'Tofta', 'Östergarn', 'Fårösund'],
            filledArray: ''
        }
        this.createGrid = this.createGrid.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount = () => {
        this.createGrid();
    }

    createGrid = () => {
        const self = this;
        const locationArr = self.state.locationArray;
        const tempArray = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < locationArr.length; i++) {
            const xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {
                    const xmlDoc = this.responseXML;
                    const windSpeed = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('windSpeed')[0];
                    const windspeed = windSpeed.getAttribute('mps');
                    tempArray.push({
                        name: locationArr[i],
                        windspeed: windspeed
                    })
                }
            };
            xhttp.open("GET", `http://www.yr.no/place/Sweden/Gotland/${locationArr[i]}/forecast_hour_by_hour.xml`, true);
            xhttp.send();
        }
        self.setState({
            filledArray: tempArray
        })

    }

    render() {
        console.log(this.state.filledArray) // <-- This works, shows me a filled array  
        console.log(this.state.filledArray[0].name) // <-- This does not work.
        return (
            <div>
                <p className="normal">Name: <span className="fatData">{this.state.filledArray}</span></p>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default GridConditionsXML;
```

Comment: I don't think you are doing anything wrong, and I think this is part of React's roadmap to have async component rendering. Normally if you are waiting for data you will need to set your state to eg. an empty array, and then setState on your data result. React will handle the rendering.

Comment: I think you should put `self.setState({ filledArray: tempArray })` inside the `onreadystatechange`. Make a try, see if my guess correct.

Comment: @intellidroid What are you trying to say?

Comment: @matrixtai That does not work. The problem is not populating the array, that part is fine. The problem is that it does it about two seconds after the rendering fires.

Comment: Sorry I cant get what you mean, react do the things like "I `render()` first even data not ready -> (wait for a while) -> Oh, data ready, I run `setState()` this time and this will call the `render()` -> I `render()` again." Are you saying that your `setState()` don't trigger the `render()` again?

Comment: What I am trying to say is that you cannot pause/halt the component rendering

Comment: @matrixtai Exactly, I know it should by default, but it doenst seem like it.

Comment: So, the situation for your is: after data come, `render()` doesn't fire. Are you sure `filledArray` will change after 2 seconds?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a for loop, you can use a map and set the state once the map is executed. That should work for you.

```
createGrid = () => {
    const self = this;
    var flag = 0;
    const locationArr = self.state.locationArray;
    const tempArray = [];
    locationArr.map(function(value, index) {
        const xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.open("GET", `http://www.yr.no/place/Sweden/Gotland/${locationArr[i]}/forecast_hour_by_hour.xml`, true);
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {
                const xmlDoc = this.responseXML;
                const windSpeed = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('windSpeed')[0];
                const windspeed = windSpeed.getAttribute('mps');
                flag++;
                tempArray.push({
                    name: value,
                    windspeed: windspeed
                })
            }
            if (locationArr.length === flag) {
                this.populateArray(tempArray);
            }
        };
        xhttp.send();
    });
  }

populateArray = tempArray = {
    this.setState({
      filledArray: tempArray,
      filledArrayLoaded: true
    });
}

render() {
    console.log(this.state.filledArray) 
    if (this.state.filledArray.length > 0) {
        console.log(this.state.filledArray[0].name) ;
    }
    return (
        <div>
            {this.state.filledArrayLoaded && ( <p className="normal">Name: <span className="fatData">{this.state.filledArray}</span></p>
        </div>)}
    )
}
```

Comment: I can, but since it fires async it does not matter. The object will still be undefined in the first render()

Comment: what you can do is set the filledArrayLoaded state to false in constructor initially and once the array is loaded, then setState the filledArrayLoaded to true. In render, check if filledArrayLoaded is true, that will load the array in the first render. I have updated the code. I havent looked at the async part of xhr, I will update it.

Comment: Maybe try setting a flag value once every xhr request is processed, and once the flag length equals the array length, trigger the setstate callback function.

Answer (score 0):

You need wait, for `this.state.filledArray[0]`, first that renders without elements.

```
import React from "react";

class ExampleComponent extends React.PureComponent {

state={ filledArray: [] }

componentDidMount = () => {
    this.createGrid();
}

createGrid = () => {
// {...}
// after some processes
this.setState({ filledArray: tempArray })
}

  render() {
    const { filledArray } = this.state;
    return filledArray.length>0?<div>have elements in array</div>:<div>no elements in array</div>
  }
}

export default ExampleComponent
```

Comment: I feel like this is the right answer, how and where will I present my now populated array?

Comment: @Tindra you can map through array elements `filledArray.length>0?filledArray .map(element=><div>{element.name}</div>:<div>no elements in array</div>` Or need create another react class for displaying content

Comment: Yes, but it will still only show "No elements in array", because there are none when render fires. 

 render() {
        const { filledArray } = this.state;
                return filledArray.length>0?<div>{filledArray.map(element=><div>{element.name}</div>)}</div>:<div>no elements in array</div>
        }
    
}

Comment: Render ALWAYS fires. You can return `null`, when havent elements, that means display nothing

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like

```
 render() {
    const { filledArray } = this.state;
    if(filledArray.length == locationArray.length){
       return(
          <div>
             <p className="normal">Name: <span className="fatData">{this.state.filledArray}</span></p>
           </div>
        );
     }
 else return(
      <div> You can display spinner/ Show some waiting msg</div>
 );
```

}

Comment: This seems like a good approach, but how do I call it again, so it renders the populated array when done? As of now, it would be a infinite spinner.

Comment: No, until your filledArray's length in not equal to locationArray.length it will not go inside if condition. as it is come to equal of locationArray.length it will render and populate your data inside your <p> tag. Whenever setSTate set the data it will fire render() function and check the if condition.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of async/await and promises to achieve Https request.

```
createGrid = async () => {
    const self = this;
    const locationArr = self.state.locationArray;
    let tempArray = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < locationArr.length; i++) {
      let response = await new Promise(resolve => {
        const xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.open(
          "GET",
          `http://www.yr.no/place/Sweden/Gotland/${
            locationArr[i]
          }/forecast_hour_by_hour.xml`,
          true
        );
        xhttp.send();
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
          if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {
            const xmlDoc = this.responseXML;
            const windSpeed = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('windSpeed')[0];
            const windspeed = windSpeed.getAttribute('mps');
            resolve(windspeed);
          }
        };
      });
      tempArray.push({
        name: locationArr[i],
        windspeed: response
      });
    }
    self.setState({
      filledArray: tempArray
    });
  };
```